# Change JS function to an object

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I asked a question awhile ago here > [Cons of MouseOver for webpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549095/cons-of-mouseover-for-webpages)  and ran into some issues with enabling/disabling events. According to the answer from the post, I was supposed to update my function as an object to call it out easily. However after a few hours of trial and error as well as online research, I still don't understand how the object works

So this is the function I want to put into an object,

```
$(function () {
    $('#01 img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#01 :first-child').fadeOut(1500)
           .next('img').fadeIn(1500)
           .end().appendTo('#01');
    }, 3000);
});
```

And this was the code provided to initialize my object,

```
var Slideshow = (function () {
    this.interval;

    this.start = function () {
        ...
        initialize
        ...
        // catch the interval ID so you can stop it later on
        this.interval = window.setInterval(this.next, 3000);
    };

    this.next = function () {
        /*
         * You cannot refer to the keyword this in this function
         * since it gets executed outside the object's context.
         */
        ...
        your logic
        ...
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    };
})();
```

So how exactly should I implement my function into the object so that it works?

Comment: So what did you actually try? And what exactly is the question? Could be anything from "*but I need to refer to `this`, what can I do*" over "*how does the code provided in that answer work*" to "*how to put the code from the first snippet into the `next` function*"…

Comment: @Bergi I tried placing the function into the object code however I think I might have placed them in the wrong areas or am I supposed to abandon some parts of my function when putting my function into the object. Basically I am lost as to where I should place my function into the code provided.

Comment: Then please show us *what* you have tried…

Comment: Btw, maybe you have done it right but didn't notice; that answer is crap. Do not use.

Comment: i dont think that code would work, that is a self-invoked function, not a object constructor

Comment: agreed i don't think you can self invoke a constructor funciton

Comment: @JamesDaly: You can (by preceding it with `new`), but it doesn't make sense :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it like this:

```
function Slideshow(container) {
    this.interval = undefined;

    this.start = function () {
        container.find("img").first().show();
        container.find("img:gt(0)").hide();
        this.interval = window.setInterval(this.next, 3000);
    };

    this.next = function () {
        var first = container.find(":first-child");
        first.fadeOut(1500, function () {
            first.next("img").fadeIn(1500);
            first.appendTo(container);
        });
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    };
}

$(function () {
    var div = $("#div01");
    var slides = new Slideshow(div);

    div.hover(function() {
        slides.stop();
    }, function() {
        slides.start();
    });
    slides.start();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/STcvq/5/

*latest version courtesy of @Bergi*

Comment: @Bergi Haha what the heck was I thinking? I don't know why I kept it as an IIFE that returned a function...

Comment: I have removed that absolutely unnecessary module IEFE around the constructor for you :-) If you now edit to make it to stop on `hover` instead of clicks (as the OP desired) I'll give it an upvote :-)

Comment: @Bergi I *think* that does it?

Comment: @Bergi Ahh I see, I reversed how the `hover` should work. And yeah, it's probably better to keep the `hover` binding outside the constructor. I'll just agree with the rest :) I think the `start` method could be "optimized" a little more, but it's really not important. Thanks for working on this - I gladly gave you credit in the answer!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, the latest code you have provided works for me.

Answer (score 0):

What you should aim to do, looking at the recommended code, is to move the logic of your setInterval inside the Slideshow.next() function. That basically covers your fadeout, fadein logic.

So your function would look something like:

```
this.next = function() {
  $('#01 :first-child').fadeOut(1500)
       .next('img').fadeIn(1500)
       .end().appendTo('#01');
};
```

in the simplest of worlds.

Ideally, you would want to instantiate your Slideshow by telling it which id it should use, by passing that in the constructor. That is, you should be able to call

new Slideshow('#01') as well as new Slideshow('#02') so that you can truly reuse it.

Then, your next function would change to look something like (assuming the id is stored in this.elementId):

```
this.next = function() {
  $(this.elementId + ':first-child').fadeOut(1500)
       .next('img').fadeIn(1500)
       .end().appendTo('#01');
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

change syntax to :

```
var Slideshow = (function () {
return {
    interval:null,
    start : function () {
        // catch the interval ID so you can stop it later on
        this.interval = window.setInterval(this.next, 3000);
    },

    next: function () {

    },

    stop : function () {
        window.clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
};
})();
```

as you are using jquery, a better ans is to create a little plugin:
http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Just remove that unnecessary module IEFE!

Comment: in this case, yes, it is useless.
But it is a alternative way if @Damienn want to make use of IIFEs